# How should I name my websites, URLs, usernames for better Google search indexing?

Tags: google-search, google, search-engines

I want to change my username on GitHub, Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter for better indexing. I want it to be in Google searches when I search my name or website.

How should I change it? For e.g. `johnsmith` / `john_smith` / `john-smith`.

**I wanted to know the effects if I use underscore instead of the hyphen/dash & vice-versa or no space.**

The same goes for URLs, which will help in better indexing.
e.g. `https://johnsmith.example` or `https://john-smith.example`

Comment: This isn't the exact same question, but the answer to it answers most of your question.  [With respect to SEO, is it preferred to use hyphen instead of period in the URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123784/with-respect-to-seo-is-it-preferred-to-use-hyphen-instead-of-period-in-the-url)

Comment: Further reading: [Squeezing all the SEO out of a URL as possible](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/squeezing-all-the-seo-out-of-a-url-as-possible)